# how to use spring data jpa repository( jackson ) to deserialize posted json which has nested data?

Tags: json, jackson, nested, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I use spring data jpa and rest to expose restful api, actually `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

My Entity definations are:

#### User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@JsonDeserialize(using = User.Deserialize.class)
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7802610584713776262L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role")
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_permissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission")
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();

    // ... getters and setters ...
    public static class Deserialize extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

        @Override
        public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String txt = jsonParser.readValueAsTree().toString();
            return JSON.parseObject(txt, User.class);
        }
    }
}
```

#### role

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
@JsonDeserialize(using = Role.Deserialize.class)
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -53314161963168175L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String roleName;
    private String info;

    @ManyToMany(
            targetEntity=Permission.class,
            cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch=FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name="roles_permissions",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_name"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="permission")
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();

    public static class Deserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Role> {

        @Override
        public Role deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String txt = jsonParser.readValueAsTree().toString();
            return JSON.parseObject(txt, Role.class);
        }
    }
}
```

#### permission

```
@Entity
@Table(name="permissions")
@JsonDeserialize(using = Permission.Deserialize.class)
public class Permission implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3716946708377038760L;
    @Id
    private String permission;
    private String info;

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch=FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Permission parent;

    public static class Deserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Permission> {

        @Override
        public Permission deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String txt = jsonParser.readValueAsTree().toString();
            return JSON.parseObject(txt, Permission.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I managed these data from web, so i follows the step:

1. post permissions to server var `host:port/permissions`
2. post roles var `host:port/roles`
3. post permissions of roles var `host:port/roles/role_id/permissions`
4. post users var `host:port/users`
5. post roles of users var `host:port/users/user_id/roles`
6. post permission of users var `host:port/users/user_id/permissions`.

But i want to combine the step 2,3 to one single operation and 4,5,6 to another single operation by posting nested data. 
For example:
assume perm1, perm2, perm3 has been created.

```
{roleName: "admin", permissions: ["perm1", "perm2"]}

{userName: "peter", roles: ["admin"], permissions: ["perm3"]}
```

I found a solution which i used in my code: the `@JsonDeserializer`. I defined deserializer for these entities, and used Fastjson to deserialize the nested data, which works.

Any has better solutions? I feel it can be done in jackson or spring, but i don't know. Any body help me?